# Add CSS to specific class which is odd

Tags: jquery, css

I have been searching out for the solution for few couple hours now, 
I want to add css for particular class which is odd.

This is how it looks.

```
form
 .form-group
 .form-group.group-inline           //group-inline odd
 .form-group.group-inline
 .form-group
 .form-group
 .form-group
 .form-group.group-inline          //group-inline odd
 .form-group.group-inline
 .form-group
 .form-group


form
 .form-group
 .form-group
 .form-group
 .form-group
 .form-group
 .form-group.group-inline          //group-inline odd
 .form-group.group-inline
 .form-group
 .form-group
 .form-group
```

So, i want to add css to only odd **group-inline** class. 
I tried using

```
.group-inline:nth-child(odd)
```

and

```
.group-inline:nth-child(2n+1)
```

but its counting every of the div which are listed together. 
I tried using jquery, but its the same.

Jquery :first selector worked fine but that only applied to the first class. Please let me know if its possible. 
I won't be able to change the html so have to do it from css itself.

any of your answer would be grateful, thank you.

> UPDATE

Thanks to @Roamer-1888
here is the jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/etb20su3/

Comment: how would you determine the odd groups?

Comment: @omi Odd as in only for the group-inline class.
1, 3, 5, 7
The Idea is to bring group-inline in same row, as the other div without group-inline stays as a block.

Comment: You're missing the `.` before `group-inline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and those `.form-group.group-inline` elements always come in adjacent pairs, then try the following jQuery, which would work for the hierarchy in the question :

```
$(".form-group.group-inline").filter(function() {
    return $(this).next().hasClass('group-inline');
});
```

If I understand correctly, and those `.form-group.group-inline` elements always come in adjacent pairs, then try the following jQuery :

```
$(".form-group.group-inline").filter(function() {
    return $(this).next().hasClass('group-inline');
});
```

Here, oddness is implicit.

However, if pairs of `.form-group.group-inline` elements can be consecutive (ie a run of four or six etc), then the above approach will not work. You might try :

```
$(".form-group.group-inline").filter(function(index) {
    return (index % 2 == 1);
});
```

Here, oddness is explicit, though ":odd" is not used.

Comment: Thanks man! That worked well. You saved my night :) 
yes having the same classes continuously, did not work. 
i have linked the jsfiddle above. Thank to you!

Comment: I've just edited to add another suggestion.